# Migrating command line script to FT API 1.0

Tags: google-fusion-tables, google-oauth

I have a simple server-side command line python script, based on the now deprecated FT SQL API using Client Login for authorization.
Every few hours I refresh my FT by inserting the updated data. It's a small table, 3000 rows.

Read the FT Migration Guide, have a Google User id, enabled the FT API and have an API key, etc.
(Switching my Google Maps application to the new API was straight forward)

But I'm confused about how to proceed with migrating a command line python script.  I see that OAuth2 is the recommended approach for authentication but it appears to me that this is a much more complicated approach than I truly need. It's not even clear to me that it will work for command line scripts.
Truly no need to prompt the user for login info (it's only me).   I realize that this must be an "Installed app" and I found the Hello,python example at
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/sample_code#ftAPIv1

Haven't tried this yet but wanted to see if anyone has experience with migrating command line scripts. (PHP would work as well)

In particular I was intrigued by a quote I found here:
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using

*"The Fusion Tables API also supports older authorization options, such as OAuth 1.0, AuthSub, or ClientLogin; however, in most cases we don't recommend using those other options. If your application already uses those options, we recommend migrating to OAuth 2.0 if possible."*

Because, frankly I'd rather not switch to OAuth 2 for such a simple task.

**UPDATE**

Forgot to mention, I run this from cron, every 3 hours.  So user input is not really possible. Though as David suggested below a one time user input is doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use your Client Login token as your auth token for your existing server-side command line app with the new API.  You'll also need to include your developer key in the request as the "key" parameter.

Comment: Thanks Warren. Sounds like the simplest approach but I need to weigh this against David's advice which is perhaps a longer term more "correct" solution.

Comment: I took the path of least resistance and this approach did indeed work. This will give me time to get more acquainted with OAuth2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple python implementation of the OAuth2 Installed Application flow here https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/python as you may have found, and yes, you should switch to this. ClientLogin deprecated just like the SQL API.

The Code requires you to open a browser and prompts you every time you use it and I'm going to speak to the author about optimizing it and having it store the Refresh Token and so it would only prompt the first time you use it.

Comment: Sounds like you don't want to spend too much time on this, but if you or someone else wanted to investigate a one-time-only prompt app, the Google library to do it is here https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#commandline

Comment: So different advice from two Google developers. One for FT, one for OAuth2 ;-).  I will probably investigate both approaches.  OAuth is new territory for me.  Not sure why it's necessary for Installed Applications.

Comment: Why not use a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount)? They are supported by the [Google API library for Python](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/wiki/OAuth2) and they don't not require a user prompt. Sounds like the best solution for this use case.

Comment: Now I have time to move to OAuth2 and investigate Service Accounts, etc.