# Use of API key to insert a row into a public Google Fusion Table

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have a public Google Fusion Table. I would like to post a HTTP request to insert a new row into the table. From my reading of the Google Fusion Table V1.0 API Documentation it seems I could use an API key (&key=) for the purposes of authentication.
However I always get the response :
    {
     "error": {
      "errors": [
       {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "message": "Login Required",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
       }
      ],
      "code": 401,
      "message": "Login Required"
     }
    }

Is the problem that the use of the API key is not enough for updating a table?

Comment: will the request be done on serverside or clientside?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Comment: I have a java application which is sending the HTTP request so in this sense it is a client. I wanted to avoid using OAuth Token due to their expiry, so in that way the API key seemed to be the best solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to pass a token with the key, but FT's still support the deprecated ClientLogin approach.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14060377/1211981